# Communicate to a device using gprs tcp/ip

Tags: android, tcp, gprs

I want to send a command to a device using an android application which supports gprs tcp/ip communication. I don't know how to establish connection between device and android application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know IP address or DNS name of the device and TCP port.
Then you can just open socket and read/write there.
However you need to ensure your device has Internet access and accessible from the Internet.

Comment: I have the ip address of the device. I have seen the tcp/ip socket code in C++. Can i use the same code for this communication? Is there any effect of gprs?

Comment: `you need to ensure your device has Internet access and accessible from the Internet.`. Why? Not needed. Just a W(LAN) connection will do.

Comment: You right network access and route to device. In case of GPRS and more modern cellular connections you usually get \31 or even \32 network with some route to internet. So ensure target device accessible 

As for code you can use Java socket
[link]http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html

I think you have to reformat your question - it's ambiguous